# Why does it say xxx is not a function

Tags: javascript, closures, unobtrusive-javascript

why is this not ok?

```
aContract = function(){};
aContract.prototype = {
    someFunction: function() {
        alert('yo');
    },
    someOtherFunction: some$Other$Function
};

var some$Other$Function = function() {
    alert('Yo yo yo');
};

var c = new aContract();
c.someFunction();
c.someOtherFunction();
```

Firebug says c.someOtherFunction is not a function

But this works just fine

```
aContract = function(){};
aContract.prototype = {
    someFunction: function() {
        alert('yo');
    },
    someOtherFunction: some$Other$Function
};

function some$Other$Function() {
    alert('Yo yo yo');
};

var c = new aContract();
c.someFunction();
c.someOtherFunction();
```

What am I missing here??? I prefer to code in javascript using the first method, which usually works fine, but doesn't seem to work correctly when I prototype.

Thanks,
~ck in Sandy Eggo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have assigned `some$Other$Function` to `aContract.prototype.someOtherFunction` before you actually create `some$Other$Function`. The order of statements matters. If you switch the order of things you'll be good:

```
var some$Other$Function = function() {
    alert('Yo yo yo');
};

aContract = function(){};
aContract.prototype = {
    someFunction: function() {
        alert('yo');
    },
    someOtherFunction: some$Other$Function
};
```

Answer (score 4):

At the time this is evaluated:

```
 aContract.prototype = { ... }
```

this has not yet been evaluated:

```
var some$Other$Function = function() { ... }
```

Thus `aContract.prototype.someOtherFunction` is set to `undefined`.

The reason the second works is because function **declarations** (which the second is, the first is an expression) are evaluated before any other statements.  There are more details here: [Named function expressions demystified](http://yura.thinkweb2.com/named-function-expressions/)

Answer (score 1):

It's due to hoisting. Function statements are moved to the top of their scope.

**Edit:** Verification Crockford's JavaScript: The Good Parts page 113.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that, in the global scope, `var` works differently than it does in function-local scopes. In function-local scopes, `var`-declared variables are lifted to the top of the function (i.e., any variable declared anywhere within a function with the keyword `var` is available anywhere else within that function). But in the global scope, perhaps only use of the keyword `function` to declare a variable yields the same result (i.e., that a variable declared with the keyword `function` will be available anywhere within that global scope, even in lines preceding that declaration).

Comment: That isn't true at all. Calling blah() displays "undefined": function blah() {
alert(x); var x = 5; }

Comment: That is not quite what happens. eg. (function(){var a = x + 1;var x = 2; return a;})() return NaN. You might be thinking more like (function(){var a = function(){return x + 1};var x = 2;return a()})()
which does return 3.